# What is the way in React to handle competing Ajax requests so just the last one goes through?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a smartsearch widget, If I type fast (which is the common scenario when someone types a name she knows), I want the request after the last letter typed to go through, not one request for each character I type.
If I fire the Ajax request in the onChange event of an INPUT tag, and I type "abcd" quick, I want to send to the server just "abcd".
Anything built into React around this?

Comment: use `debouncing` of `loadash`, [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)

Comment: @CodeManiac exactly what I was looking for, put as an answer

Comment: No need as this just an comment, there are already answers present on so :)

Comment: @CodeManiac the duplicate answers you posted use the word "debounce", I would never guess this is the term I need to use, hence I would never find it (as I would use the wrong search key words).